# how to use SQL dependency in Azure SQL

Tags: websocket, signalr, azure-sql-database

I realized that  the Azure SQL doesn't support SQL dependency .
And i am using signal R for refresh cache on database changes.
Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Azure SQL Managed Instance does support service broker and SQL Dependency? Are you willing to try that PaaS service?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer,
Actually, we have web application(runing on azure app) and need to catch latest updated-insert-delete actions from Azure SQL.
Do you have any sample? Is there any link for how create managed instance and enable service broker